# Setting the units of each column of an existing dataframe in R

Tags: r, dataframe, units-of-measurement

I have a dataframe with a bunch of columns and a separate list that has the units of each column in it. I feel like the following should work:

```
library(units)
df = data.frame(1:4, 2:5, 3:6)
units = c("mg/L", "pH", "s")
for (i in length(df)){
  set_units(df[[i]], units[[i]])
}
```

However `set_units()` tries to set `units[[i]]` as the unit (which unsurprisingly isn't an SI unit), rather than reading the `i`th value of units. I've tried various approaches with `lapply()` and `mapply()` too but haven't been able to get it to work and google isn't bringing up anything relevant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the documentation `set_units()` is a pipe-friendly function that by default expects the units to be passed as symbols.  For standard evaluation use the argument `mode = "standard"`.

```
library(units)
library(purrr)

df = data.frame(1:4, 2:5, 3:6)
units = c("mg/L", "pH", "s")

df %>%
  map2_dfc(units,  ~set_units(.x, .y, mode = "standard"))

# A tibble: 4 x 3
    X1.4  X2.5  X3.6
  [mg/L]  [pH]   [s]
1      1     2     3
2      2     3     4
3      3     4     5
4      4     5     6
```

Comment: Thanks, I couldn't figure out how to pass the units list correctly.

Answer (score 1):

You can do

```
df = data.frame(1:4, 2:5, 3:6)
units = c("mg/L", "pH", "s")
for(i in 1:ncol(df)){
  units(df[ , i]) <- units[i]
}
df

      X1.4   X2.5  X3.6
1 1 [mg/L] 2 [pH] 3 [s]
2 2 [mg/L] 3 [pH] 4 [s]
3 3 [mg/L] 4 [pH] 5 [s]
4 4 [mg/L] 5 [pH] 6 [s]
```

There are different problems with the code that you provide. First, `i in length(df)` will not use every column number for `i` but only the number `3` in your case. Second, I don't know the `set_units()` function but apart from that the output of this function is not assigned to any object in the loop. Third, you do not need double `[[]]` here. Finally, you can use `units()` as it is described in the  [package documentation:](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/units/units.pdf)

```
# The easiest way to assign units to a numeric vector is like this:
x <- y <- 1:4
units(x) <- "m/s" # meters / second
```